# insufficient access on cross reference Id during insert of child detail record in after insert of parent record

Tags: apex, trigger, dml, after-trigger

```
    public static void createQuoteLineItem(sales_Toolkit__c[] newQuote, OpportunityLineItem[] oppLine {
    List<Conversion__c> newQline = new list<Conversion__c>();
    Id parentQuoteId; //there's only ever one.
     for(Sales_Toolkit__c st : newQuote){
          parentQuoteId = st.Id;
      }
     for(OpportunityLineItem qt : oppLine){
          Conversion__c quoteSheet = new Conversion__c();
          quoteSheet.To_Theme__c = qt.Product2Id;
          quoteSheet.Opportunity_Product__c = qt.Id;
          quoteSheet.cabinet__c = qt.product2.Cabinet__c;
          quoteSheet.brand__c = qt.product2.Brand__c;
          quoteSheet.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Conversion__c.getRecordTypeInfosbyDeveloperName().get('New_Build').getRecordTypeId();
          quoteSheet.Sales_Toolkit__c = parentQuoteId;
          newQline.add(quoteSheet);
      }
      system.debug(' newQline  ' +newQline);
      insert newQline;
  }
```

There's no required field other than the parent Sales_Toolkit__c, name is an auto-number. It's running in the context of After_Insert trigger of the Sales_Toolkit__c object

debug on what is getting inserted

```
Conversion__c:{To_Theme__c=01t5Y000006VyPBQA0, Opportunity_Product__c=00k1g000008DsOFAA0, Cabinet__c=a9X1O00000007iaUAA, Brand__c=a9W14000000TR5yEAG, RecordTypeId=01214000001NcbsAAC, Sales_Toolkit__c=a4W1g000000anLEEAY}
```

I'm running this as the system admin and have access to the objects/fields.. I could manually go created a Conversion__c record with nothing in it.

Full erorr:

```
 EXCEPTION_THROWN [298]|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: a9W14000000TR5y: []
```

Comment: Check if user has access to Brand__c record a9W14000000TR5yEAG (as error indicates).

Comment: and i'm an idiot who can't read my own debug logs